# Automatically placing of text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I need to do plot a lot of variables against each other. In each of these plots I would like to automatically place information from a linear regression model in the upper left corner of the graph.

Taking the mtcars dataset for an example, I would like a piece of code I could use that would give me the the R2 and p-value from a linear regression model in the top left corner of the graph no matter what variables I plotted against each other. I have made a solution, where I plot R2 and P in the title, but since I need another title it's not optimal.

```
ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {
  
  require(ggplot2)
  
  ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
    labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 1),
                                 " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 1)))
    }

disp_vs_wt_cyl4 <- mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl=="4") 

ggplotRegression(lm(disp ~ wt, data = disp_vs_wt_cyl4)) +
  geom_point(size = 3.74, colour = "#0c4c8a") +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `annotation_custom` in your plot, which would allow you to have a separate title. In this example, we allow a title to be passed to your function:

```r
ggplotRegression <- function (fit, title) {
  
  require(ggplot2)
  lab <- grid::textGrob(label = paste0(
    as.character(as.expression(fit$call$formula)), "\n",
    "Adj R\u00b2 = ",
    signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 1),
    ",  p = ", signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 1)),
     x = unit(0.05, "npc"), 
     y = unit(0.9, "npc"), just = "left",
     gp = grid::gpar(size = 14, fontface = "bold"))
  ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], 
                               y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    ggtitle(title) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
    annotation_custom(lab)
}
```

So we can do:

```
disp_vs_wt_cyl4 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl=="4") 

ggplotRegression(lm(disp ~ wt, data = disp_vs_wt_cyl4), "My Title") +
  geom_point(size = 3.74, colour = "#0c4c8a") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that will save me time! Using your code, however I get a graph where iit says NULL instead of disp ~wt. Below the NULL I get the correct R2 and p. Could you explain a bit how your function works?

Comment: I think there is a typo in ```as.expression```. ```f``` should be ```fit```.